# Ignore IDataErrorInfo notifications

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a collection that I can use in my application where I can ignore the DataErrors? Currently, my BusinessObject implements the IDataErrorInfo interface, but I have a readonly control that I do not want to receive those notifications.

I tried using a DataTemplate with a TextBlock that has the property ValidatesOnDataErrors=False, but this didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is not a collection I am looking for... but maybe a way to bypass it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the control's `Validation.ErrorTemplate` to null using a style.

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also, to clarify, the "ValidatesOnDataErrors" property should be used on the binding not the control itself.

The other alternative is to wrap your bound objects in some view model/adapter that doesn't implement `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: I figured that much. I believe i'm going to wrap my business class that doesn't implement that interface... will make my life that much easier. Thanks, I appreciate it